# SPSS ordinal data

Tags: spss

I have a ordinall variable say `A`, which has labels 'absolutely yes','yes','neutral', 'no', 'absolutely no'. I want to select only the data which gives value `yes` for the variable `A`. Then I want to use these data only and compare some ordinal variables. 
 So how can I isolate only the data with value `yes` for the variable `A`

Comment: Have a look at the `select if` command.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
USE ALL. *removes any filters you have in place.
COMPUTE filter_$=(A = 'yes'). *creates a filter variable.
VARIABLE LABELS filter_$ "A = 'yes' (FILTER)". *labels it.
VALUE LABELS filter_$ 0 'Not Selected' 1 'Selected'. *labels the values.
FORMATS filter_$ (f1.0). *formats the filter variable.
FILTER BY filter_$. *this is the uses the filter variable you just created.
EXECUTE.
```

You can also point-and-click your way to the answer under Data -> Select Cases. Select the "If condition is satisfied" button and make your selections from there.